# Type mismatch in overloaded operator (writing pipelines)

Tags: c++, c++11

Just testing/learning to write pipelines in C++ overloading the `|` operator, the following program
fails to compile:

> invalid operands to binary expression candidate template ignored:
>   ...
>   could not match 'bitset' against 'vector'

It seems as if the compiler is trying to use the standard | definition.
The code works with explicit call and explicit type parameters set.

```
// g++ -std=c++11 Pipeline.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// ..............................................................
// ..............................................................
std::string dup (std::string s) {
  return s + s;
}

// ..............................................................
// ..............................................................
template <typename TI, typename TO>
std::vector<TO> operator | (const std::vector<TI> & in, std::function<TO(TI)> f) {
  std::vector<TO> out;
  for (auto i : in) {
    out.push_back ( f(i) );
  }
  return out;
}

// ..............................................................
// ..............................................................
int main () {
  std::cout << " hello " << std::endl;

  std::vector<std::string> vs = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};

  auto res = vs | dup;
  // OK: vector<string> res = operator|<string,string> (vs, dup);

  for (auto s : res) { std::cout << s << std::endl; }

} // ()
```

Complete error message:

```
Pipeline.cpp:29:17: error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('std::vector<std::string>' and 'std::string (*)(std::string)')
  auto res = vs | dup;
             ~~ ^ ~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/bitset:1045:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match 'bitset' against 'vector'
operator|(const bitset<_Size>& __x, const bitset<_Size>& __y) _NOEXCEPT
^
Pipeline.cpp:13:17: note: candidate template ignored: could not match
      'function<type-parameter-0-1 (type-parameter-0-0)>' against
      'std::__1::basic_string<char> (*)(std::__1::basic_string<char>)'
std::vector<TO> operator | (const std::vector<TI> & in, std::function<TO...
                ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Is that the complete error output? Why does it complain about `bitset` since there are no bitsets in the shown source?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've just attached the complete error msg.

Comment: The problem is in template function.If you replace `template` with `std::string `it will work fine.

Comment: A function pointer is not a `std::function`, and so template argument deduction will fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Template argument deduction does not look through implicit conversions. A function pointer is not a `std::function`, so the compiler can't deduce what template arguments to instantiate your `operator|` with. In general, `std::function<...>`, where `...` contains a template parameter, is not the correct way to accept an arbitrary function or function object.

Instead, accept any type for the functor:

```
template <typename TI, typename F>
/* something */ operator | (const std::vector<TI> & in, F f)
```

and then figure out the return type.

The return type is a `std::vector`, whose value type is the type returned by calling `f` on an element of `in` - in other words, `decltype(f(in[0]))`. However, `f` could return a reference type, and you really want the vector's value type in those cases to be the type referred to. Use `std::decay` (or `std::remove_reference`) to strip away any reference-ness:

```
template <typename TI, typename F>
auto operator | (const std::vector<TI> & in, F f) -> std::vector<typename std::decay<decltype(f(in[0]))>::type> {
    std::vector<typename std::decay<decltype(f(in[0]))>::type> out;
    /*...*/
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12207a2bc36573e4).

Comment: I know this is off-topic but isn't it true that whatever you can do with a trailing return type you can technically also do with a regular return type? That a trailing return type is just syntactic sugar?

Comment: @templateboy it is not correct, check the [C++11 faq](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#suffix-return).

Comment: @templateboy In general, a trailing return type can be transformed into a non-trailing return type by replacing occurrences of the parameters `t` with a call to `std::declval<T>()` where `T` is equivalent to `decltype((t))`. In this case, the return type would be `std::vector<typename std::decay<decltype(std::declval<F&>()(std::declval<const std::vector<TI>&>()[0]))>::type>`. Doing so definitely does not help readability, and it violates DRY by repeating the types of the referenced parameters.

Answer (score 0):

An analogous solution to that of T.C.

```
template <typename CONT, typename F>  // types: container , function
auto operator | (const CONT & a, F f) {
  // find out input type and output type
  using TI = typename CONT::value_type;
  TI aux;
  using TO = decltype(f(aux));
  // do the task
  vector<TO> res;
  for (auto & i : a) {
    res.push_back( f(i) );
  }
  return res;
}
```

**EDIT**
Complete "experimental" code. Changed the operators to
be `==` : transform, `!=` filter, and `>>=` reduce/visit, thus
avoiding the need of parentheses in expressions like `vs == dup != lengthy  != contains == length >>= add;` (we need transform and filer have the same precedence, and reduce have lesser). Don't know if that poses collateral problems in other expressions using them.

```
// g++ -std=c++1y Pipeline.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// ..............................................................
// transform
// ..............................................................
template <typename CONT, typename F>
auto operator == (const CONT & a, F  f) {
  using IT = typename CONT::value_type;
  IT aux;
  using OT = decltype(f(aux));
  vector<OT> res;
  for (auto & i : a) {
    res.push_back( f(i) );
  }
  return res;
}

// ..............................................................
// filter
// ..............................................................
template <typename CONT, typename F>
auto operator != (const CONT & a, F  f) {
  using IT = typename CONT::value_type;
  IT aux;
  vector<IT> res;
  for (auto & i : a) {
    if (f(i)) res.push_back( i );
  }
  return res;
}

// ..............................................................
// reduce / visit
// ..............................................................
template <typename CONT, typename F>
auto operator >>= (const CONT & a, F  f) {
  for (auto & i : a) {
    f(i);
  }
  return f;
}

// ..............................................................
// ..............................................................
int main () {
  vector<string> vs = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};

  int sum = 0;

  auto dup = [] (const string &s) -> string { return s+s; };
  auto lengthy = [] (const string &s) -> bool { return s.length()>6; };
  auto contains = [] (const string &s) -> bool { return s.find('f') != string::npos; };

  auto length = [] (const string &s)   { return s.length(); };
  auto add = [&sum] (int i) { sum += i;};

  // == transform
  // != filter
  // >>= reduce / visit
  vs == dup != lengthy  != contains == length >>= add;

  cout << sum << endl;

  auto res1 =  vs == dup != lengthy  != contains;

  for (auto & s : res1) { cout << s << endl; }

} // ()
```

Comment: 1) Deduced return type is C++14 only; 2) you are passing the container by value, which is a bad idea; and 3) This `operator |` will also match everything, which probably isn't a good idea either. You'd want to constrain it somewhat.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for your suggestions. 1. would not be a problem. 2. changed to `const CONT &` and 3. yes, but `|` mimics the unix pipe (maybe `>>` is OK).

Comment: The problem is that this can interfere with other things. If you have `enum B { x = 0, y = 1, z = 2, w = 4};`, for instance, `x | y` suddenly will stop compiling because your overload gets picked up instead.

Comment: @T.C. How would you suggest restricting the input type to say any iterable container ? Or if you think that is a bad idea, what kind of constrain would you suggest ?

Comment: @T.C. Yes that would be a problem. I'm posting my (by the moment) experiment. Maybe I will help to the discussion.

Comment: You make the assumption that you operate only on vector (since you always return some kind of vector) yet this isn't explicit in your template arguments or operator declaration. Maybe you should templatize on type `TI` and have `std::vector<TI>`as argument to your operators.

Comment: @FélixCantournet Not exactly. I assume that I operate on some `iterable` thing (hence `for (auto & i : a) {`). If the type used is not `iterable` it simply won't compile (as desired, no further restriction to add here). On the other hand, I have to return something. Why not `vector` (which is in turn `iterable`).?

Comment: @cibercitizen1 Ok. However I wonder what kind of error the compiler will throw... I mean that I don't think it will throw a template mismatch error. Looks like yet another place where concepts might be a nicer way to do things. Then again do we really want more things in c++? I'd say Nope.

Comment: A good thing about using a trailing return type is that SFINAE applies to it. In the code in my answer, if `f(in[0])` isn't well-formed, the operator would be simply removed from the overload set. You can do something similar.